# Issue with calling from matlab to python module I wrote using keras

Tags: python, matlab, keras

I trained a model using keras in python and try to integrate it with matlab code.
In matlab I'm calling the python function by:

```
res = py.mymod.myfun();
```

In my python module there is an import from keras:

```
# mymod.py
import keras.models
def myfun():
    ...
    ...
```

The error in matlab is:

```
Error using __init__><module> (line 65)
Python Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Error in __init__><module> (line 2)
from . import backend

Error in mymod><module> (line 3)
import keras.models

Error in <frozen importlib>_call_with_frames_removed (line 222)

Error in <frozen importlib>exec_module (line 665)

Error in <frozen importlib>_exec (line 626)

Error in __init__>reload (line 166)
        _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
```

I verified both mymod and keras are in python path by:

```
P = py.sys.path;
if count(P,modulePath) == 0
    insert(P,int32(0),modulePath);
end
if count(P,kerasPath) == 0
    insert(P,int32(0),kerasPath);
end
```

What might be the cause of this error?
After removing the import of keras, obviously the error dissapeared.

Comment: By the way, calling this function from Python works without any errors so it must be related to the way Matlab calls it. In addition, calling this function from Matlab after omitting the import of Kerala also works.

Answer (score 1):

```
import io
import sys

f = io.StringIO()
try:
    sys.stdout = f
    sys.stderr = f
except:
    pass
```

This will work for you

Answer (score 0):

It's because Keras writes to stderr the line "Using Tensorflow as Backend" (Or whatever backend you are using). If you comment that out, the import should work.